# .Net Custom Control BackColor=Transparent gives Black

Tags: c#, winforms, firefox, user-controls, transparency

Ok I am creating (trying) a custom Control based on System.Windows.Forms.Button. If I set the BackColor (this.BackColor) to Color.Transparent I get a black background. Any other colour works fine.

1) How Do I set it so that the parent BackColor comes through?

and

2) How would "you" create the Firefox goBack and goForward buttons and Address bar?

Comment: Consider using WPF, which will make this _much_ easier.

Comment: 1 - I have no idea, I don't use winforms because it's deprecated and useless. 2 - I would use WPF, the default and preferred option to create Windows applications since the .Net Framework 3.0 was released in 2006.

Comment: @HighCore Where have you heard that winforms is deprecated?

Comment: @johnkoerner I don't need to "hear" such a thing. The same way I don't need to "hear" that we need air to breathe. winforms doesn't support anything. it's useless. It has been deprecated implicitly and automatically since WPF was born.

Comment: @HighCore `don't use winforms` is the same as `use WPF` unless you don't use `.NET`, is there any other UI technology for us to choose when programming desktop applications in .NET?

Comment: @Slaks If I could use WPF I would but the company insists upon Windows Forms... that was the Question (@HighCore) so suggestions like use WPF are pointless and irrelevant to the Question.

Comment: @DaveGordon if "the company" insists on using winforms they should be told you can't do such thing as a custom, transparent button in winforms. At least not without losing a horrendous amount of time and resorting to a horrendous amount of hacks, time that you could spend in adding business functionality instead. winforms does not support looking good. If they use winforms, they should conform themselves with the default, ugly, square, Windows-95 like stuff.

Comment: People create [good looking](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20091124/razorfone-conceptual-windows7-wpf-multi-touch-retail/) applications using WPF because it enables you to, without wasting years in horrible "owner draw" techniques. People who "insist on using winforms" clearly do not care about User Experience or good looking applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) How Do I set it so that the parent BackColor comes through?

Setting the `BackColor` of a child control equal to the parent `BackColor` in the constructor is a problem, because the parent `BackColor` is probably not yet the good one as the constructor is called.

This is especially true if you intend to change it during runtime.

You can overcome this very simply by using the good old reliable DataBinding mechanism of Windows Forms in your parent control constructor:

```
myChildControl.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", this, "BackColor");
```

As the BackColor of your parent changes, it will propagate to your child control anytime.